# Close One Tab within Chrome via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

Using Excel VBA to open a Google Chrome tab with a pre-filled Google Form link URL that syncs to a Google Sheet.

Would ideally like the opened tab to close after a second.

However the various shortkeys that I send this application close all the tabs. Anyone know a trick of how to close the last open Chrome tab via VBA?

''' ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink myURL
''' Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

Have Tried:

''' Application.SendKeys ("^W")
''' Application.SendKeys ("%{F4}")

Answer (score -1):

Sod's law worked it out within a few mins of posting

```
Application.SendKeys "^(w)"
```

Comment: It works only if you are able to make the browser having the focus. Otherwise, it acts on the application running the code...

Comment: Yes, @FaneDuru's alert is important. Always avoid using "Application.SendKeys"